# Are children's helmets with styling less safe?

Tags: safety, helmets

In a couple well received [answers](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/49735/is-it-safe-to-wear-a-helmet-without-a-plastic-covering/49739#49739) to a recent question it is suggested that sliding on the road is an important consideration for helmets.

A number of children's helmets now are available with spikes or ears or fins that would seem to have a meaningful impact of the ability to slide.

Are these helmets less safe?

Comment: On a mass(of head) vs thickness (of helmet foam) comparison, children's helmets are probably better than adult helmets for protecting against still/slow fall-over impacts.  I've rarely seen a kid go 30 speed.

Comment: As always, safety is not an absolute or easily measure thing. If a child wears a helmet because of the additional bling, the helmet is safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are probably as safe as any other children helmets.

When buying, check if they are certified by local certification agencies

See this : http://www.bhsi.org/standard.htm

Comment: Standards compliance is a good place to start, but that seems to focus on impact and say nothing about a test of sliding or neck protection. If no real research supports the other question's answers I suppose this is the best that can be said.

Answer (score 4):

Sad to say, I think with children the main injury mechanisms are falling off their bike at low speed or getting hit by a car. Both are blunt force trauma that the helmet can mitigate with little sliding.

Contrast against a road or mountain bike going downhill at 50 kph and wiping out at a corner.

Comment: This is what I suspected. Different threats or kids not being expected to have the speed for sliding to matter, but I would like some evidence.

Comment: It is also important to put the helmet on correctly. Quite often you'll see children (but also adults) with helmet straps that are too loose. And then there are those who wear it too far back on the head.

Comment: Yes, many times unstrapped all together. The new helmets with magnetic straps are wonderful, you just bring the two sides close by and they snap together.  You can even do it one handed, which is great for kids and adults alike.

Answer (score -1):

just from personal experience from looking at childrens helmets I can tell you that a lot of childrens helmets with ears/spikes or fins have them mounted very high up on the helmet, often near or at the top. Which should not have a meaningful impact on the child's ability to slide as these protrusions from the helmet are likely to never make contact with the ground.